# Избежать катастрофЫ или избежать катастрофУ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, падежи

"Он считает, что катастрофу избежал только благодаря..." - читаю я у автора. Возможно, ситуация аналогичная с "не обращай внимание/внимания". И все же правильным будет "избежать катастрофы" или пригоден винительный падеж?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: **избежать катастрофы.**

ИЗБЕГАТЬ,  нсв. **кого-чего или с инф.** 1. Сторониться кого-, чего-л., намеренно уклоняться от чего-л.  И. разговора, чьего-л. общества, расспросов, объяснений, взгляда, встречи. 2. Избавляться, спасаться, отделываться от чего-л. И. наказания, выговора, неприятности, опасности, беды, болезни. И. аварии. <Избегаться, -ается; страд. Избежать.

В ней целый перечень идет, какие меры нужно предпринимать, чтобы **избежать катастрофы.** [А. С. Новиков-Прибой. Цусима (1932-1935)]

В. п. обозначает направленность на объект,  здесь же идет речь об уклонении от объекта, поэтому используется только Р. п.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь родительный падеж - избежать (кого-чего) катастрофы.

Винительный ничего здесь обозначать не может (кроме неграмотности автора), потому что он здесь просто невозможен.

Правда тут есть одна особенность. "Избегать" относится к тем крайне немногочисленным глаголам, которые требуют родительного падежа, но позволяют образовывать от себя страдательное причастие. Избегаемый - вполне нормативно. Это позволяет предположить, что винительный падеж при глаголе "избегать" когда-то был вполне возможным. Более того, не исключено, что и станет таковым в будущем. Но на данный момент нормативен только родительный ("избежать катастрофы"), что и устанавливается по любому словарю.

Comment: В этом случае одна из запятых лишняя. Либо перед "потому", либо после "потому" перед "что" (второй абзац).

Comment: Да, согласна, спасибо. Здесь - лишняя. А в начале предложения я часто её ставлю как интонационную, назло всем врагам.))) Видимо уже сама себя перехитрила.

Comment: Хаха))) *А в начале предложения я часто её ставлю как интонационную.* Я так и думал, что это бывает как продолжение мысли, только новым предложением.

Comment: Да, именно так. Это "потому" как бы относится к предыдущему предложению - и на него паданет ударение. Поэтому хочется отделить его от "что".  Но правила предписывают в начале предложения этот составной союз не разделять. Возникает непонимание и критика со стороны формалистов. Да ладно бы только у меня...